# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderation

As we enter the second week of the public beta, we desperately need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image] [image] [image] [image]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections in several weeks.**

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: thanks Robert. I'd just like to add that anyone who wishes to comment on our moderation, this is the place to do it (meta.gis.stackexchange.com in general that is, not necessarily this question). Feedack is welcome.

Answer (score 3):

I think moderation of this site has been great.  However, I can't help noticing that three of the four moderators have been *in absentia* for fairly lengthy periods: two weeks, four weeks, and over eight weeks.

(**Update** These stats were based on activity on the meta site: I didn't realize it was separately tracked.  Three of the moderators still appear to be active on the parent site, allowing for the holidays (although one has just resurfaced after a long absence).  But one of them hasn't been seen in either place for six weeks.)

I don't hear the lone fourth moderator complaining, but when half the original moderators seem to have given up on the site altogether, that does not bode well...

Comment: Thanks for the positive assessment of our work thus far Bill. I think volunteers will always wax and wane in their involvement. It would be good to have a method for resigning one's post though. In any case we'll probably be seeing moderator elections soon as the first of the SE sites, has recently had theirs: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-exchange-moderator-elections-begin/. For what it's worth I think you'd be a great moderator, should you be inclined to take on that duty.

Comment: Thanks, Matt, for your confidence.  You have raised my principal concern: how can a moderator arrange to resign or take time off?  It may be too much to expect busy professionals to volunteer their time for long periods and be able to sustain a consistently high level of involvement throughout.  That is one reason to engage several moderators, of course.  But their number is usually so small that the prolonged absence of one or two of them may unduly burden those who remain (depending on how active the site becomes).